# How to SELECT all points within a GeoJSON polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geojson, intersection, select

I have a GeoJSON polygon, and a table with lots of points. I want to `SELECT` all points that are within an arbitrary GeoJSON polygon.

How can I do that with PostGIS SQL?

Comment: What do you mean with GeoJSON polygon? Do you have that saved into a file on your hard disk or what?

Comment: I have it as a JSON object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html)

```sql
select * 
from points p
where ST_Within(
    p.geom,
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[...]}')
)
```

Edit: [`ST_Intersects`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) works also (need to set `SRID` on GeoJSON, and transform):

```sql
select row_to_json(t) 
from (select * from table 
where st_intersects(
    st_transform(
        st_setsrid(
            ST_geomfromgeojson('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[...]}'),
        4326), 
    3857), 
table.geom)) as t;
```

Comment: Ansewer is on point :)... But you may be interrested to know there is a JavaScript library for processing Geojson turf.js - https://github.com/Turfjs/turf. If you are considering for a web based implementation

Comment: How can I do a subquery on this also? ie. instead of `FROM select * from table`, I want to do `FROM (select * from table where height>1500) as sub` - but this doesn't work. Why?